# Google Assistant Smart Home may return error 500 when doing Request Sync

Tags: google-smart-home

I am doing Request Sync for my users because I implemented a new device type.

For some users it succeeds, but for some users I got errors with status 500 as a response of Request Sync like below.

```
{
  "error": {
    "code": 500,
    "message": "Internal error encountered.",
    "status": "INTERNAL"
  }
}
```

I noticed the following rule about this error

1. If the error occurs in the Request Sync for a user, the same result will occur if I try the same thing for the same user immediately afterwards.
2. However, if I make a request to that user a day later, the request to the user may be successful.

I looked at the following document, but there is no description about the 500 status error.
https://developers.google.com/assistant/smarthome/develop/request-sync

Do you know why this is happening? Also, if you know the solution, please let me know.

**Edited on April 22, 2021**

The script is the following. It is written in NodeJS.

```
const smarthome = require('actions-on-google');
const app = smarthome.smarthome({
    jwt: require('config.json')
});

const agentUserIds = ["xxxxx", "yyyyy"];
const sleep = msec => new Promise(resolve => setTimeout(resolve, msec));
const requestSync = async () => {
    for (userId of agentUserIds) {
        await app.requestSync(userId)
            .then(() => {
                console.log("Request sync success");
            })
            .catch(err => {
                console.log("Request sync error");
                console.error(err);
            });
        await sleep(1000);
    }
};

requestSync();
```

As a result, I got the following output. It succeeds for some specific users and fails for some specific users.

```
Request sync error
{
  "error": {
    "code": 500,
    "message": "Internal error encountered.",
    "status": "INTERNAL"
  }
}

Request sync success
```

Comment: Can you provide an example request so that people can better answer this question?

Comment: I'd also be curious to see the implementation, as it may be something like too many parallel calls/quota issues

Comment: did you ever figured out? i have some issue: very frequent random 500

Answer (score 0):

Hi Can you check you are sending the correct API-Key in the Header, related to the users / agenuserId for which the Call is getting failed.